# PHP login for website giving "wrong password" error with correct password

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

Shoutout to the YouTube user "mmtuts" because this is basically a copy from his tutorial (at least I learned something) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LC9GaXkdxF8).

This is my first attempt for a website with a login system.

TL;DR: I ran into the problem where not even the correct passwords work with any user (aparently the user is accepted since I had the error "wronguser" aka user not found in the database but then I found my mistakes).

I am running my database using MySQL and Apache (using XAMPP). I've tried to rewrite all the names on the database and the main PHP index where the website is with the login inputs on a modal.

```
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['Password']); <!-- CHECKS IF INSERTED PASSWORD = DATABASE PASSWORD FOR INSERTED USER -->
        if ($pwdCheck == false) { <!-- IF PASSWORD DOESN'T MATCH WITH DATABASE PASSWORD FOR INSERTED USER THEN GO TO THIS "WRONG PASSWORD" ERROR PAGE (KEEPS GOING TO THIS PAGE) -->
          header("Location: ../index.php?error=password_errada1"); 
          exit();
    }
    else if($pwdCheck == true) { <!-- IF THE PASSWORD IS CORRECT THEN OPEN SESSION FOR THE INSERTED USER -->
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idAluno'];
      $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['NumeroAluno'];
      $_SESSION['userPrimeiroNome'] = $row['PrimeiroNome'];
      $_SESSION['userUltimoNome'] = $row['UltimoNome'];
      $_SESSION['userAno'] = $row['Ano'];
      $_SESSION['userTurma'] = $row['Turma'];
      $_SESSION['userRequisitou'] = $row['Requisitou'];

      header("Location: ../index.php?login=login_sucesso");
      exit();
    }
```

Looked for answers and tried to fix it for at least 1 hour now. Sorry if my post is going against any rules that I might not know about. I am so done because I know stuff like this it's always a dumb mistake.

EDIT 1: I can provide more code if wanted.

```html
$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "loginsystem";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Erro de conexão: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

dbStructure Code:

CREATE TABLE `alunos` (
  `idAluno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NumeroAluno` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `PrimeiroNome` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `UltimoNome` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Ano` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `Turma` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Requisitou` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: Are you sure the $row['Password'] contains a hash created by password_hash()? Go to the link - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: here `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);` ,passing both times `mailuid` ,i think this should be `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss",$mailuid, $password)` .

Comment: @Swati Yeah I tried that before and again now, doesn't solve the problem, and it probably shouldn't since the tutorial I saw actually had that mistake of having "$mailuid, $password)" amd then he corrected himself to "$mailuid, $mailuid)".

Comment: @AakashMartand I tried to understand but I don't know how to verify that exactly...

Comment: @PedroCantante Okay try to post your `code where you have written your query` with `dbstructure`.

Comment: @PedroCantante just check in the DB that you're saving password in simple text or in some encrypted form. If it's simple text then this function won't work.

Comment: @AakashMartand Posted the code for the db structure

Comment: @PedroCantante would you please share any password saved in your DB?

Comment: @AakashMartand Of course http://prntscr.com/nrpmum

Comment: @PedroCantante You're saving passwords as plain text. Use `password_hash($password)` for saving passwords in your database instead of just `$password`. After that password_verify() function would work. Or else just compare `if($password == $row['Password'])` but this is not a secure way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was saving the passwords manually using the database page and obviously the passwords were getting saved has plain text and not getting hashed, so when I tried to login using my PHP code the inserted password was getting hashed and the hashed password getting compared to the plain text password.

Solved this by creating a signup which creates users with hashed passwords so that the PHP compares HASHED / HASHED and not HASHED - NON-HASHED.

Could be solved aswell by not hashing the password anywhere (unsafe but easy).

Answer (score -1):

Your password is not being hashed.

Try replacing the code

```
if ($pwdCheck == false)
```

with

```
if($password != $row['Password'])
```

If it works, recheck your script where your password is being hashed.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**: Please change the else if part as well, and check again. I don't see any other mistakes.

Replace

```
else if($pwdCheck == true)
```

with

```
else if($password == $row['Password'])
```

This should probably solve your problem.

Comment: It is working then. My mistake. Add if($password != $row['Password']; I have edited the main answer as well.

Comment: Still the same output, "wrongpassword" page. Thanks tho.

Comment: I suppose you will have to change the else if part as well.